# How restrict tableview to fill cell second time if it filled first time

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

In my TableView I am setting image and two label, it filling fine. But when I scrolling TableView down and then re view that filled cell than it will refill. now i am filling my ImageView with the image which come from URL so it will create load for my user.

So can i restrict my TableView that if my cell is filled first time that it will not fill again.

This is my code :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)atableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *SimpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableIdentifier";

    UITableViewCell * cell = [atableView  dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: nil];

    if(cell == nil) {

        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]
                initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                reuseIdentifier:SimpleTableIdentifier];

        ChannelList *channelList = nil;
        if (searchedData.count ==0) {
            channelList = [channelAllData objectAtIndex:[indexPath section]];
        } else {
            channelList = [searchedData objectAtIndex:[indexPath section]];
        }


        UIImageView *aImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 10, 50, 50)];
        aImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tv-defolt.png"];
        NSString * mystr = [channelList channelLogo];

        if (mystr.length !=0) {
            //get a dispatch queue
            dispatch_queue_t concurrentQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
            //this will start the image loading in bg
            dispatch_async(concurrentQueue, ^{
                NSString * str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://manektech.net/mttv/Channel/%@",[channelList channelLogo]];
                NSData *image = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:str]];

                //this will set the image when loading is finished
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    aImageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:image];
                });
            });
        } else {
            aImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tv-defolt.png"];
        }

        [cell addSubview:aImageView];


        UILabel *nameTextLabel =  [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(80, 15, 175, 20)];
        nameTextLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        nameTextLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        nameTextLabel.text = [channelList channelName];
        nameTextLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:14];
        [cell addSubview:nameTextLabel];

        UILabel *genreTextLabel =  [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(80, 35, 175, 20)];
        genreTextLabel.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];
        genreTextLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

        NSString * str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ | %@",[channelList channelType],[channelList channelCounry]];

        genreTextLabel.text = str;
        genreTextLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:14];
        [cell addSubview:genreTextLabel];


    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray;


    }
    return cell;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)atableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

     NSString *SimpleTableIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Cell%d%d",indexPath.section,indexPath.row]; /// set different idenfifier for all cell

    UITableViewCell * cell = [atableView  dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: SimpleTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:SimpleTableIdentifier] autorelease];
        /// Add UIImageView and UILable here 
    }    
}
```

Comment: does it better to use SDWebImage instead of lazy table.

Comment: try that, that is useful for AsynImage which download image in background and store in our Directory but this is logic for load only first time that cell again that cell not loaded

Comment: @PingDanehog also see what your question , your question is my cell load only first time so i post this answer...

Comment: Yes, your answer has helpfull +1. but i am thinking it as option that if SDWebImage will help me to decrease my app download or method i am using is better.

Comment: yes its also right if your application or that class depends on download bunch of data from web with Image then its helpful but although for resuse of cell if you use abour deffirent identifier then its not load again when uitableview scrolled..

Comment: Why not use booleans in your Data class, and use them when your image is downloaded make it true, and stop downloading.. ?

Comment: That mean it will not gonna call image URL again right, for that cell?

Comment: ya try that... i do like your requirement in my app with different logic.. first time when it wdownload image i store it in my directory and display it in my cell but this,mlogic is work for me also...

Comment: @iphonic no here not required to use any boolean variable, you can do with this condition like we use (cell == nil) so if cell with that identifier is nil then its enter inside of this condition otherwise not load that data...

Comment: Nice answer, i have checked that is my cell will call imageurl second time by using log . and it does not. so it will not use extra network download. and that is better for me.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) to avoid lazy table scrolling.
It uses caching and avoid requesting images URL everytime.

Answer (score 0):

Crete Your `UILabel` and `UIImageview` in Between

```
if(cell == nil) 
{
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]
                initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault

  .
  .
  .

    // create `UILabel` and `UIImageview`  here add add it to cell.contentView
}
```

And both in `cell.contentView`

Comment: does it better to use SDWebImage instead of lazy table.